# Youtube API for video download

Tags: java, php, youtube-api

I want to create a PHP/Java application that would be able to download  videos from youtube.I think there is no direct youtube apis from google.Have any third party apis available? please help me.

Comment: Downloading videos from YouTube is against the YouTube EULA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use third part apps [clive](http://clive.sourceforge.net/), it is a command line tool. Hope it helps you.

You can also use [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) in addition to convert different format from flv or mp4 that you download from youtube.

Comment: Thank you.I want to extract the audio on mp3 format.Is it possible with ffmpeg?

Comment: This [link](http://www.ffmpeg.org/general.html#SEC3) said it supports mp3 but external library is needed.

Comment: Is there any tool or library like clive for java?

Answer (score -1):

I was recently able to find this  [site](http://mediakeepapi.info/) they provide a REST api for downloading videos, mp3 it seems like it is easy to use