# How can we Download Youtube videos to a random Android/ios device through Rest APIs?

Tags: youtube-api, video-streaming

I want to write an API using which I can download selected videos to n number of devices.

Is there any API from youtube as such?

Answer (score 0):

Downloading YouTube videos using the API is against their [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/api-services-terms-of-service).

However, based from this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36922740/how-can-i-download-youtube-video-using-their-youtube-json-rest-api-with-python#comment61407124_36922740), try the [youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/) that is written in Python which you may use for downloading a YouTube video given its URL.

Here's another reference:

- [Youtube API for video download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907409/youtube-api-for-video-download)

  > Downloading videos from YouTube is against the YouTube EULA.
  >
  > You can use third part apps [clive](http://clive.sourceforge.net/), it is a command line tool. Hope it helps you.
  >
  > You can also use [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) in addition to convert different format from flv or mp4 that you download from youtube.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have kind of different requirement. I want to download same videos in multiple devices at same time. through some API calls. I was expecting some kind of API exposed from Youtube in which we can pass device id and youtube url or something. so that it can download to corresponding devices.